# Android: Canvas is cleared on rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, rotation

I implemented some functionality with my android application which is allow user to draw. But as we know on rotation activity and views is destroyed, so my Canvas is destroyed also, is there any way to save drawn state on rotation?

Any advice is appreciated.

**UPD :**

So the problem can be in next part of my code, I'm storing array of my path and color inside the view which one is DESTROYED on rotation also, and my arrays is cleared after that

```java
class CanvasCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    companion object {
        private const val STROKE_WIDTH = 12f
    }

    private var path = Path()
    var drawColor : Int = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorBlack, null)

    private val paths = ArrayList<Pair<Path, Int>>()
    private val undonePaths = ArrayList<Pair<Path, Int>>()
```

**UPD 2:**

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.paintr">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**UPD 3:**

Any suggestions how it can be implemented with

```java
onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState
```

Comment: can you please share your manifest code

Comment: Yeah, sure - added

Comment: You have to save/restore your custom view's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So partially success was made with

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in manifest inside your Activity Tag

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for storing data related to UI elements. Storing data in viewmodel prevents it from being destroyed on configuration changes(or other changes which you haven't foreseen) and is generally considered a good practice.

Even then if you want to go forward with saveInstanceState or restoreInstanceState then you have to define a class which should contain data you want to store/restore and make it implement [Parceable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable). Then on your activity you need to define onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState?.putParcelable(key, model);
}
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    model = outState?.getParcelable(key);
}
```

Here model is the object of that class and key is a string used for storing that.